# Keras: How to compare K.sum(y_true) with 0 in custom loss?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I want to define custom loss, but seems it fails to compare keras tensor `K.sum(y_true)` with single value `0`.

```
def custom_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    if(K.sum(y_true) > 0):
        loss = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
        return loss
    else:
        loss = 0.0
        return loss
```

I also tried `K.eval()` inside loss function to get numpy array and it failed.

```
def custom_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_np = K.eval(y_true) 
    #if(K.sum(y_true) > 0):
    if(np.sum(y_true_np) > 0):
        loss = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
        return loss
    else:
        loss = 0.0
        return loss
```

**UPDATE:**

```
def custom_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    if(K.greater(K.sum(y_true), 0)):
        loss = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
        return loss
    else:
        loss = 0.0
        return loss
```

It produces error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Also I have tried to combine suggested `tf.cond` with keras functions:

```
def custom_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = tf.cond(K.greater(K.sum(y_true),0), K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1), 0.0)

    return loss
```

It produces error:

```
     22 def custom_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
---> 23     loss = tf.cond(K.greater(K.sum(y_true),0), K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1), 0.0)
     24 
     25     return loss

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in cond(pred, fn1, fn2, name)
   1718   with ops.name_scope(name, "cond", [pred]) as name:
   1719     if not callable(fn1):
-> 1720       raise TypeError("fn1 must be callable.")
   1721     if not callable(fn2):
   1722       raise TypeError("fn2 must be callable.")

TypeError: fn1 must be callable.
```

Seems like I need to write it in pure tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `if` and `else` (or `K.eval`) inside a loss function won't work since the lines in `custom_loss_keras` are executed during model compilation, not model fitting.

Instead of calling `tf.cond`, you can use `K.switch`:

```
def custom_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = K.mean(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
    condition = K.greater(K.sum(y_true), 0)
    return K.switch(condition, loss, K.zeros_like(loss))
```

Answer (score 1):

Keras backend does not understand > as an operator, you have to use the built-in Keras logical operator for greater than:

```
K.greater(x, y)
```

where in your case:

```
x = K.sum(y_true)
y = 0
```

Source: https://keras.io/backend/#backend-functions

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with TF, but I would think that tf.cond should do the trick. Try re-visiting the docs, else I guess try asking a new question because this has now become a different issue than your title suggests.